# check if values are between two values pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, boolean

I have a two values that are being found in a for loop like so:

```
for i in range(df_zones.shape[0]):

   filter_max = df_labels[df_labels['Labels'] == i].sort_values(by='level').iloc[-1]
   filter_min = df_labels[df_labels['Labels'] == i].sort_values(by='level').iloc[0]
```

I have another dataframe with 4 columns of measurements with a timeseries index, like so:

| DateTime | meas1 | meas2 | meas3 | meas4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-1-1 | 1.1 | 1.2 | 1.3 | 1.1 |

There are 1000's of rows of data.

What I am trying to do is have another column that is labeled as 'isZone', where this means, are any of the values in the row between filter_max and filter_min.

| DateTime | meas1 | meas2 | meas3 | meas4 | isZone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-1-1 | 1.1 | 1.5 | 1.5 | 1.7 | 0 |
| 2022-1-2 | 2.2 | 1.4 | 1.5 | 1.7 | 0 |
| 2022-1-3 | 3.1 | 1.2 | 1.3 | 1.1 | 1 |
| 2022-1-4 | 4.1 | 1.2 | 1.3 | 1.1 | 1 |
| 2022-1-5 | 5.1 | 1.2 | 1.3 | 1.1 | 1 |

I have read about the pandas between function. But I really can't figure out how to make this work. Is there a quicker way to do this in numpy? any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Which column shuold be compared to `filter_max` and `filter_min` to decide if it's between two values?

Comment: @CeliusStingher all of the columns should be checked. If any or all of them have a match a 1 should be returned else 0.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is `np.where()` but the problem is adapting it to check for all columns, therefore I'm not sure it's necessarily going to be faster than pandas' between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method above took 30 minutes to compute, the below method is done in under 2 seconds.

In the end, the best method was to append all the items to their own lists, and make a function that combines all the pandas between checks and checks row-wise if there is a one or not.

'''

```
    def arrayBoolCheck(arrays):
        df = pd.DataFrame(arrays).T
        df_new = (df.iloc[:, :] == 1).any(axis=1).astype(int)
        return df_new

    isZone1, isZone2, isZone3, isZone4 = [], [], [], [], []
    for i in range(df_zones.shape[0]):

        filter_max = df_labels[df_labels['Labels'] == i].sort_values(by='level').iloc[-1]
        filter_min = df_labels[df_labels['Labels'] == i].sort_values(by='level').iloc[0]
    
        isZone1.append(df_instrument[f"meas1"].between(filter_min, filter_max, inclusive='both').astype(int).values)
        isZone2.append(df_instrument[f"meas2"].between(filter_min, filter_max, inclusive='both').astype(int).values)
        isZone3.append(df_instrument[f"meas3"].between(filter_min, filter_max, inclusive='both').astype(int).values)
        isZone4.append(df_instrument[f"meas4"].between(filter_min, filter_max, inclusive='both').astype(int).values)

# Zone Labels Dataframe
     df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
            self.arrayBoolCheck(np.array(isZone1)),
            self.arrayBoolCheck(np.array(isZone2)),
            self.arrayBoolCheck(np.array(isZone3)),
            self.arrayBoolCheck(np.array(isZone4))],

        index=[f"isZone1",
               f"isZone2",
               f"isZone3",
               f"isZone4"]).T
```

'''

I found that keeping the measurements in their respective columns was better for the analysis. but the same function could be used to combine them all into one column if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with `apply` and pandas' [between](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df_zones['Flag'] = df_zones.apply(lambda x: 1 if x.between(filter_min,filter_max).any() else 0,axis=1)
```

How about trying with `.T` and using a list-comprehension this way?

```
df_zones['Flag'] = [1 if df_zones.T[x].between(min_,max_).any() else 0 for x in df_zones.T]
```

Or without the transposing:

```
df_zones['Flag'] = [1 if df_zones.loc[x,:].between(min_,max_).any() else 0 for x in df_zones.index]
```

Comment: I did have something close to this and wondered if there was a way to do it in a list comprehension style for more speed but it is a tricky problem

Comment: As per my comment, the fact it requires to go through all columns in a row-by-row basis makes the complexity a lot higher. You can't have a vectorized approach, because you are not working with a vector (column) but a matrix (set of 4 columns)

Comment: Check the edit please, maybe it helps.

Comment: I have applied your solution it is running through, all be it painfully slow. I might try to break each column down into an array and see if its any faster. Even with concurrency its still a lot of time and I need speed.

When the loop finishes I will update everything this end.